# sapply() returns list instead of character vector

Tags: r, list, types, character, sapply

I'm trying to extract the most representative and most generic keywords from a set of journals (using tf-idf). I've created two structures:
-ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf is the dataframe with all keywords from all journals and their parameters. Find below the first 10 elements as a sample

```
dput(ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf[1:10,])
structure(list(ISSN = c("03029743", "03029743", "03029743", "03029743", 
"03029743", "14327643", "16130073", "10504729", "14327643", "14327643"
), word = c("artificialintelligence", "mathematicalmodels", "logicprogramming", 
"problemsolving", "semantics", "evolutionaryalgorithms", "informationanalysis", 
"robotics", "metaheuristics", "optimization"), n = c(16L, 11L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L), total = c(1050L, 1050L, 
1050L, 1050L, 1050L, 317L, 129L, 124L, 317L, 317L), tf = c(0.0152380952380952, 
0.0104761904761905, 0.00952380952380952, 0.00952380952380952, 
0.00952380952380952, 0.0315457413249211, 0.0697674418604651, 
0.0645161290322581, 0.0252365930599369, 0.0252365930599369), 
    idf = c(2.70805020110221, 2.45022109180011, 3.23867845216438, 
    2.2454266791541, 2.40576932922928, 2.14006616349627, 3.74950407593037, 
    3.34403896782221, 2.54553127160443, 2.17396771517195), tf_idf = c(0.0412655268739384, 
    0.0256689828664773, 0.0308445566872798, 0.0213850159919438, 
    0.0229120888498026, 0.0675099736118697, 0.261593307623049, 
    0.215744449536917, 0.0642405368228249, 0.0548635385532354
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

STEM_journals is a dataframe with all parameters from each analysed journals. Find below first 10 elements as well

```
dput(journals_STEM[1:10,])
structure(list(Title = c("Nature Reviews Materials", "National vital statistics reports : from the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, National Center for Health Statistics, National Vital Statistics System", 
"Reviews of Modern Physics", "Chemical Reviews", "Nature Energy", 
"Nature Reviews Chemistry", "Nature Materials", "Chemical Society Reviews", 
"Advances in Physics", "Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Computer Vision"
), ISSN = c("20588437", "15518922", "00346861", "15206890", "20587546", 
"23973358", "14764660", "03060012", "14606976", "15505499"), 
    Categories = c("Biomaterials;Electronic, Optical and Magnetic Materials;Energy;Materials Chemistry;Surfaces, Coatings and Films ", 
    "Life-span and Life-course Studies ", "Physics and Astronomy ", 
    "Chemistry ", "Electronic, Optical and Magnetic Materials;Energy Engineering and Power Technology;Fuel Technology;Renewable Energy, Sustainability and the Environment ", 
    "Chemical Engineering;Chemistry ", "Chemistry;Condensed Matter Physics;Materials Science;Mechanical Engineering;Mechanics of Materials ", 
    "Chemistry ", "Condensed Matter Physics ", "Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition; Software"
    ), Categories4dist = c("Biomaterials ElectronicOpticalMagneticMaterials Energy MaterialsChemistry SurfacesCoatingsFilms", 
    "Life-spanLife-courseStudies", "PhysicsAstronomy", "Chemistry", 
    "ElectronicOpticalMagneticMaterials EnergyEngineeringPowerTechnology FuelTechnology RenewableEnergySustainabilitytheEnvironment", 
    "ChemicalEngineering Chemistry", "Chemistry CondensedMatterPhysics MaterialsScience MechanicalEngineering MechanicsofMaterials", 
    "Chemistry", "CondensedMatterPhysics", "ComputerVisionPatternRecognition Software"
    ), Top.Level = c("Physical Sciences and Engineering", "Physical Sciences and Engineering", 
    "Physical Sciences and Engineering", "Physical Sciences and Engineering", 
    "Physical Sciences and Engineering", "Physical Sciences and Engineering", 
    "Physical Sciences and Engineering", "Physical Sciences and Engineering", 
    "Physical Sciences and Engineering", "Physical Sciences and Engineering"
    ), Primary.Level = c("Chemistry", "Mathematics", "Physics and Astronomy", 
    "Chemistry", "Energy", "Chemical Engineering", "Chemistry", 
    "Chemistry", "Materials Science", "Computer Science"), Secondary.Level = c("Chemistry (General)", 
    "Statistics and Probability", "Physics and Astronomy (General)", 
    "Chemistry (General)", "Fuel Technology", "Process Chemistry and Technology", 
    "Chemistry (General)", "Chemistry (General)", "Materials Science (General)", 
    "Computer Graphics and Computer-Aided Design"), `Group by JCRCats k= 22` = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L), Journal_KW = list(`20588437` = NA, 
        `15518922` = NA, `00346861` = NA, `15206890` = NA, `20587546` = NA, 
        `23973358` = NA, `14764660` = NA, `03060012` = NA, `14606976` = NA, 
        `15505499` = NA), Journal_KW_Gen = list(`20588437` = NA, 
        `15518922` = NA, `00346861` = NA, `15206890` = NA, `20587546` = NA, 
        `23973358` = NA, `14764660` = NA, `03060012` = NA, `14606976` = NA, 
        `15505499` = NA)), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 17L, 
24L, 26L, 30L, 31L, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've created a function that brings together all keywords from papers with the same ISSN (i.e. same journals) and, using , returns the most meaningful ones (supposedly as character type)

```
journal_main_kw<- function (tfidf_df, jr_issn, threshold){
  
  if (jr_issn %in% tfidf_df$ISSN) {
    aux<- tfidf_df[(tfidf_df$ISSN==jr_issn)&(tfidf_df$tf_idf)>threshold,]$word
    aux<-unlist(aux)
    return(aux)
  }
  else return(NA)
}
```

(I have a similar one to return the least meaningful; only change is a < instead of a >)

I have tested this function isolatedly, passing a single ISSN, and it returns a character vector as expected. Even if if it includes more than one word, it is still a character type (checked with typeof). However, when I try to iterate over the whole STEM_journals ISSN column, the function fills the new column with lists instead of characters (other than that, it works correctly from a qualitative point of view):

```
journals_STEM$Journal_KW<-sapply(journals_STEM$ISSN, journal_main_kw, tfidf_df=ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf,threshold=term_threshold)
```

Furthermore, even if I have the NA return condition in my function, some cells in the result column are filled with character(0) -when no elements match the return condition- which are hard to remove because they are lists (I guess, because looking for length 0 element is not working in this code). I can avoid this, I think, but the list issue is major trouble for what I plan to do later.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong? I've read a similar question, stating that since I'm getting an undefined number of results, they must come in list format, but I have no issues with the function until I use sapply:

```
journal_generic_kw(ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf,"01628828", 0.5*term_threshold)
[1] "algorithms" "datamining" "estimation"
typeof(journal_generic_kw(ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf,"01628828", 0.5*term_threshold))
[1] "character"
```

Comment: This isn't a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `term_threshold` isn't defined (or I missed it) and the ISSN-values from `journals_STEM$ISSN` aren't in `ISSN_STEMKW_tf_idf`, thus your function always returns `NA`.

Comment: `sapply` can return a vector (as opposed to a list) **iif**: (1) all returns are "simple", i.e., can be in a vector (and not fancy `list`-embodied); (2) all return values are the same class; and (3) all return values have the same length (and that length is 1 or more). If any of those are not true, it will not simplify, it will return a `list`.

Comment: The only one that might not fit is that all returned values are the same length, I guess. I'll have to use a for in this one, then :(
Thanks for the explanation, I was only aware of conditions 1 and 2

Comment: @r2evans - that's a super helpful answer I couldn't find clearly documented elsewhere (particularly same length requirement). If that's not already an answer somewhere on SO, would you be willing to add it?

Comment: @r2evans - I just posted a question on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76577714/13210554 if you want to chime in for an answer. Thanks!