# sapply won't simplify to vector

Tags: r

I can't get `sapply()` to `simplify` my `list` to a `vector` which is what I thought it was supposed to do. Is this expected behavior and if so, what alternative do I have to end up with a `vector`?

```r
# sample list
l1 <- list(1:2, 3)

# returns list not vector
sapply(l1, cumsum, simplify = 'vector')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is the documented behavior of `sapply` so I don't think there's a way around it other than `unlist` as you noted. (Although, I don't think any character input for `simplify` has any meaning other than `array`. I don't think I've ever seen anything used there besides TRUE, FALSE or "array".)

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of taste, but I don't see what's inelegant about `l1 |> sapply(cumsum) |> unlist()`

Comment: `sapply`' is actually `lapply(<list>, cumsum) |> simplify2array()`. If simplification is not possible, `simplify2array` produces slight overhead. So for unlisting, `lapply(<list>) |> unlist()` directly is more efficient.

Comment: If you want to unlist without calling it unlist, you could also `l1 |> Map(f = cumsum) |> Reduce(f = c)` for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and documented behavior. In your example, the `cumsum()` returns values of different `length`s which cannot be simplified together.
Per the documentation, `sapply()` will only simplify if all elements are of same length.

From 'Details' section of `?sapply`

> Simplification in sapply is only attempted if X has length greater than zero and if the return values from all elements of X are all of the same (positive) length.

```r
# elements of different length
l1 <- list(1:2, 3)

# all elements same length
l2 <- list(1, 2, 3)

# cannot return vector if different lengths
sapply(l1, cumsum)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3

# returns vector
sapply(l2, cumsum)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In this case you can just use `unlist()` to convert the output to a `vector`.

```r
sapply(l1, cumsum) |> unlist()
#> [1] 1 3 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Furthermore, `sapply()` is actually `lapply(<list>, cumsum) |> simplify2array()` under the hood. If simplification is not possible, `simplify2array` produces a slight overhead. So for unlisting, `lapply(<list>) |> unlist()` directly is more efficient.

Finally, although the documentation isn't completely explicit about acceptable `character` values of the `simplify` argument:

> `simplify`
> logical or character string; should the result be simplified to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array if possible? For `sapply` it must be named and not abbreviated. The default value, `TRUE`, returns a vector or matrix if appropriate, whereas if `simplify = "array"` the result may be an `array` of “rank” (
> =
> =length(dim(.))) one higher than the result of `FUN(X[[i]])`.

I don't think any character input for `simplify` has any meaning other than `"array"`. I don't think I've ever seen anything used there besides `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `"array"`.